# How to read .hql file (to run hive query) in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have .hql file with huge amount of queries. It is running slow in hive. I want to read and run .hql file using pyspark/sparksql.

I tried `count = sqlContext.sql(open("file.hql").read()).count()` but gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/data/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/data/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"missing EOF at ';' near 'db'; line 1 pos 36"
```

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in your `.hql` file. Could you add the contents of the file to your question?

Comment: The file has only two query to test.

use db;
show tables;

Comment: Is your database's name `table`? `table` is a reserved word.

Comment: no. database name is db.

Comment: try `show tables in db;`